# Laravel Voyager, How to translate table using eloquent Model

Tags: laravel, web, voyager

This below is the sample code for translate, but it's not translate for field com_id. anyone if you have any solution please help me,

Thank you !!

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use TCG\Voyager\Traits\Translatable;


class Job extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'jobs';
    use Translatable;
    protected $translatable = ['title', 'desc','gender'];

    public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Company', 'com_id');
    }

}
```

Comment: is the whole table not getting translated or is it just the `com_id` field?

Comment: i recommend using https://github.com/spatie/laravel-translatable, it is much simpler

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you for any answers now I fine one solution to fix it

```
echo $job->company->getTranslatedAttribute('title');
```

If everyone have problem like me you can do that.

Thanks!!